# SQLAlchemy not finding tables, possible connection issues

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to one our our internal databases using the following code:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
        user=config3.CANVAS_USERNAME,
        passw=config3.CANVAS_PWD,
        host=config3.CANVAS_BOUNCER,
        port=config3.CANVAS_PORT,
        db='cluster17dr'
    ))
metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
    print(metadata.tables)
```

And my only result is a table called 'spatial_ref_sys', which I assume is some kind of metadata.  I know that my login stuff is correct, because this works perfectly:

```
with ppg2.connect(
        database='cluster17dr',
        user=config3.CANVAS_USERNAME,
        password=config3.CANVAS_PWD,
        host=config3.CANVAS_BOUNCER,
        port=config3.CANVAS_PORT) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM canvas.switchman_shards LIMIT 10'

        cur.execute(sql)

        res = cur.fetchall()
        print(res)
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing in my connection using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Try specifying `metadata.reflect(..., schema="canvas")`?

Comment: That did it.  Create an answer and I'll accept:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if no schema name is specified, SQLAlchemy will only give you tables under the default schema. If you want to reflect tables in a schema other than the default schema (which defaults to `public` in PostgreSQL), you need to specify the `schema` keyword to `.reflect()`:

```
metadata.reflect(..., schema="canvas")
```